# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'web-vitals' in '/app/src'

Tags: reactjs

Everything works perfectly fine on my local computer, but once I deployed my react app in heroku, it starts to give this error.

The things I have tried already,

1. npm install web-vitals --save-dev
2. delete node module and npm install
3. downgrade web-vitals from 2.1.4 to 2.1.2
4. npm update

but no matter what I do, my heroku keeps on crashing and keeps on showing this same error

Answer (score 8):

### Issue

The error "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'web-vitals'" is because of missing **web-vitals** package, make sure the web-vitals package is installed in devDependencies.

### Install web-vitals

To install the web-vitals, just run the following command in the root directory of the project and re-run the server

```
npm install --save-dev web-vitals
```

If the error is not resolved, try to delete your node_modules and package-lock.json (not package.json) files, re-run npm install

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:** Go to "*src*" folder then in "*index.js*"

**Step 2:** Delete `import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';`, `reportWebVitals();` this two line of code from there and you are ready to go.

[Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyZpX.png)

Answer (score 0):

**1. Try deleting node modules and package-lock.json then clearing the cache:**

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm -f package-lock.json

#  clean npm cache
npm cache clean --force

npm install
```

**2. If still it does not work then :**

open your package.json file and make sure it contains the web-vitals package in the devDependencies object.

```
{
  // ... rest
  "devDependencies": {
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4" //your version
  }
}
```

then manually re-run `npm install`.